# How to add characters to the end of each string in column based on group by and order in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, tidyr

I have a table that looks like so:

```
Injury BL Time Delay (sec) Acute Time Delay (sec) Chronic Time Delay (sec) Acute Area Deficit (mm2)
1  Moderate                0.35                   1.10                     0.60                     1.84
2    Severe                0.42                   1.47                     0.86                     3.04
3  Moderate                0.45                   1.02                     0.65                     1.80
4  Moderate                0.42                   0.97                     0.70                     1.76
5    Severe                0.40                   1.55                     0.80                     3.12
6  Moderate                0.37                   0.96                     0.65                     1.65
7    Severe                0.32                   1.64                     0.75                     3.34
8    Severe                0.40                   1.44                     0.90                     3.24
9  Moderate                0.47                   1.01                     0.82                     1.77
10 Moderate                0.41                   0.90                     0.67                     1.51
11 Moderate                0.38                   0.86                     0.57                     1.78
12   Severe                0.39                   1.59                     0.70                     3.27
```

What I would like to do is add a '**_1**' to each Injury value based on group (Server_1, Moderate_1, Severe_2, Moderate_2, etc).

Current code is this but it is not adding it distinctly to each value so my output are all '**_1**'

```
my_data[] <- lapply(my_data, function(x) paste("1", x, sep="_"))


Injury BL Time Delay (sec) Acute Time Delay (sec) Chronic Time Delay (sec) Acute Area Deficit (mm2)
1  1_Moderate                0.35                   1.10                     0.60                     1.84
2    1_Severe                0.42                   1.47                     0.86                     3.04
3  1_Moderate                0.45                   1.02                     0.65                     1.80
4  1_Moderate                0.42                   0.97                     0.70                     1.76
```

I wanted to use group_by and pipe but got an error and did not know how to call each group as a distinct value and this gave me an error.

```
update_df <- my_data %>%
  group_by(Injury) %>%
  lapply(function(x) paste("1", x, sep="_")) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, factor)
```

Comment: What logic defines a group? Row #? # of times that specific Injury has appeared? Max cumulative # of times any one specific injury has appeared?   It would be helpful to define your expected output specifically so we don't make a guess that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: My apologies - yes. How you went about it your answer was what I was looking food (# of times the group shows up - or an index value per group row value). Thank your for your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing that you're looking for cumulative appearance of each injury:

```
my_data <- tibble(Injury = c("Injury", "Moderate", "Severe", "Moderate", "Moderate", 
  "Severe", "Moderate", "Severe", "Severe", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Severe"))

my_data %>%
  group_by(Injury) %>%
  mutate(Injury_num = paste(Injury, row_number(), sep = "_")) %>%
  mutate(num_Injury = paste(row_number(), Injury, sep = "_")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
   Injury   Injury_num num_Injury
   <chr>    <chr>      <chr>     
 1 Injury   Injury_1   1_Injury  
 2 Moderate Moderate_1 1_Moderate
 3 Severe   Severe_1   1_Severe  
 4 Moderate Moderate_2 2_Moderate
 5 Moderate Moderate_3 3_Moderate
 6 Severe   Severe_2   2_Severe  
 7 Moderate Moderate_4 4_Moderate
 8 Severe   Severe_3   3_Severe  
 9 Severe   Severe_4   4_Severe  
10 Moderate Moderate_5 5_Moderate
11 Moderate Moderate_6 6_Moderate
12 Moderate Moderate_7 7_Moderate
13 Severe   Severe_5   5_Severe
```

Comment: It's unclear to me from the question whether the OP wants the number or the Injury first, as both are shown.   Thanks @GenesRus for the suggested edit.